# Cargar DBGRID en Delphi con varios xml

Tags: delphi

Tengo una aplicación de facturación donde si no hay internet se guarda el ticket en un archivo xml. En la ventana principal tengo un DBgrid con los últimos movimientos del día.

La idea es poder reimprimir o enviar a facturar con el webservice si no hubo internet, por ejemplo, aparte de contabilizar el total de dinero ingresado en el día o turno.

Ahora bien si cargo un TClientDataSet con un xml de ticket me aparecera solo "ese ticket". ¿De que manera puedo hacer un query o bucle para cargar todos los ticket en una sola grilla?

¿Podria iterar sobre todos los archivos que tengan fecha de hoy? De hecho yo guardo el fichero con la fecha en el nombre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que yo sepa automáticamente no se puede.
Tendrás que ir cargando los diferentes ficheros utilizando un `TClientDataset` (imagino que los has guardado también con el `TClientDataset`) e ir añadiéndolos por ejemplo a otro `TClientDataset2`. Este último es el que tienes que "enganchar" al grid.
Es decir, el recorrido por los diferentes ficheros para cargarlos debes hacerlo tú manualmente.